# YAML using json_query to print specific value array with filter string contained dot

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have problem to filter array from output that i've got from some module.
So this below is the output of the module that i have put it to some variable, and then i want to show/print only specific value from this variable. Maybe you guys can help me?

```
{
  "extraConfig": [
    {
      "_vimtype": "vim.option.OptionValue",
      "key": "svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware",
      "value": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "_vimtype": "vim.option.OptionValue",
      "key": "guestOS.detailed.data",
      "value": "bitness='64' distroName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux' distroVersion='8.2' familyName='Linux' kernelVersion='4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64' prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'"
    }
  ]
}
```

This above is the value of variable *summary*, then i want to get only **prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'**, is it possible?

I have tried using *?contains* but still got empty value, then i tried this below but got error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'method' object is not iterable"}

```
- debug:  
    msg: "{{ vmhost_info | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    keyvar: 'guestOS.detailed.data'
    query: "instance.config.extraConfig[?key == '{{ keyvar }}'].value"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your existing query is pretty close; it returns the string value:

> bitness='64' distroName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux' distroVersion='8.2' familyName='Linux' kernelVersion='4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64' prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'

There are a couple of ways of getting at the value of `prettyName`.  One option is to first split the string into multiple lines. If we split the string on `'` , each line begins with the key name. That is, this task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        (vmhost_info | json_query(query))  |
        first |
        split("' ")
      }}
  vars:
    keyvar: 'guestOS.detailed.data'
    query: "instance.config.extraConfig[?key == '{{ keyvar }}'].value"
```

Results in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "bitness='64",
        "distroName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux",
        "distroVersion='8.2",
        "familyName='Linux",
        "kernelVersion='4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64",
        "prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'"
    ]
}
```

Now that we have a list of items, each one beginning with the key name, we can use the `select` filter to extract the `prettyName` value:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        (vmhost_info | json_query(query))  | first |
        split("' ") |
        select('match', '^prettyName') | first |
        split('=')
        | last | replace("'", "")
      }}
  vars:
    keyvar: 'guestOS.detailed.data'
    query: "instance.config.extraConfig[?key == '{{ keyvar }}'].value"
```

Which yields:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)"
}
```

We use the `select` filter to select only those items in the list that start with `prettyName`, which gives us a single item list. The `first` filter gives us the first item from the list, which we then split on `=` to get a `(key, value)` tuple. The `last` filter gives us the value, and then strip the single quotes using `replace`.

Comment: I tried to use block of debug that you gave, but still got error 

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'. String: {{\n  (vmhost_info | json_query(query))  |\n  first |\n  split(\"' \")\n}}"}`

Comment: You must be using an older version of Ansible. This was tested (and runs without error) on Ansible (core) 2.12.6 (and Jinja2 3.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

Select the item from the list

```yaml
  keyvar: "guestOS.detailed.data"
  data: "{{ vmhost_info.instance.config.extraConfig|
            selectattr('key', 'eq', keyvar)|first }}"
```

Replace the delimiting spaces with newlines and equal signs with colons. Create the dictionary *params*

```yaml
  params: "{{ data.value|replace(pattern1, newline)|
                         replace(pattern2, colon)|
                         from_yaml }}"
  pattern1: "' "
  pattern2: "="
  newline: "'\n"
  colon: ": "
```

gives

```yaml
  params:
    bitness: '64'
    distroName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
    distroVersion: '8.2'
    familyName: Linux
    kernelVersion: 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
    prettyName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    vmhost_info:
      instance:
        config:
          extraConfig:
            - _vimtype: vim.option.OptionValue
              key: svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware
              value: 'TRUE'
            - _vimtype: vim.option.OptionValue
              key: guestOS.detailed.data
              value: >-
                bitness='64' distroName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux' distroVersion='8.2'
                familyName='Linux' kernelVersion='4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64'
                prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'

    keyvar: "guestOS.detailed.data"
    data: "{{ vmhost_info.instance.config.extraConfig|
              selectattr('key', 'eq', keyvar)|first }}"

    params: "{{ data.value|replace(pattern1, newline)|
                           replace(pattern2, colon)|
                           from_yaml }}"
    pattern1: "' "
    pattern2: "="
    newline: "'\n"
    colon: ": "
            
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: params
    - debug:
        var: params.prettyName
```

gives the value of the attribute *prettyName*

```yaml
  params.prettyName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)
```

---

Q: ***"There is no simple way I guess?"***

A: The filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json) seems to be a candidate to make it simpler. But, unfortunately, it

- works with lines only
- doesn't preserve the case of the keys, and
- doesn't remove the quotation as [promised](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/ini)

```yaml
    params: "{{ data.value|replace(pattern1, newline)|
                           community.general.jc('ini') }}"
    pattern1: "' "
    newline: "'\n"
```

gives

```yaml
  params:
    bitness: '''64'''
    distroname: '''Red Hat Enterprise Linux'''
    distroversion: '''8.2'''
    familyname: '''Linux'''
    kernelversion: '''4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64'''
    prettyname: '''Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'''
```

Comment: it looks like long way to split string in array, there is no simple way i guess?

Comment: I added an example of *community.general.jc*. However, the simplest way would be a custom filter. Do you want to try it?

Comment: not sure because i haven't use community module. i'll do research for it first.

Comment: It's powerful too. You'll have to install [jc](https://pypi.org/project/jc/). I recommend it.

Comment: If i user ansible tower with few worker under it, so i need to install this "jc" to all of the worker? bcs currently i use this ansi as a user, and there is a team who manage this ansi env

Comment: You need it on the controller only. What is preventing you from testing it?

Answer (score -1):

late answer but anyway useful for others ...

```bash
SO-73629493$ cat test.json
{
  "extraConfig": [
    {
      "_vimtype": "vim.option.OptionValue",
      "key": "svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware",
      "value": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "_vimtype": "vim.option.OptionValue",
      "key": "guestOS.detailed.data",
      "value": "bitness='64' distroName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux' distroVersion='8.2' familyName='Linux' kernelVersion='4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64' prettyName='Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)'"
    }
  ]
}
SO-73629493$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{extraConfig|json_query(\"[?key=='guestOS.detailed.data'].value\")|join("")|regex_replace(\"^.*prettyName='(.*)'$\",\"\1\")}}" -e @test.json
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)"
}
```

explanation:

the json_query gives an array with one element, so i join it to get a string. over the string i can call regex_replace with a backreference to get what you want.